# Logcat issues (pausing, buffer, output redirection)

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, logging, logcat

I've searched around for everything that seems to be capable of affecting logcat, but I just can't find an answer to this problem.  I'm debugging a large application that dumps several hundred logcat messages to screen per second.  In Eclipse, I'm using a regular expression to filter by log tag, but this is where things get weird.  The "pause" button keeps on activating for no apparent reason, and given the massive volume of new messages, before I can get the logs for the specific sequence of events I'm investigating, they'll be overwritten, a little at a time.  I've even set breakpoints and tried to capture the logs bit by bit with the "export" button, but the app is multithreaded and they still disappear too quickly because of messages from other threads.  It would be nice to increase the buffer somehow, or make old messages stick around, though at this point I'm willing to dispense with it altogether and just output it to a file, but I'm not sure how to filter by log tag using my regular expression from the command line.  What are my options?

P.S. I have been looking around and I hope this isn't redundant--I haven't found anything specifically addressing my problem, though I have of course run across abundant related threads that don't quite help.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem to this. I was working on application which communicate to web server and download a huge amount of data. I had logs almost for every variable and I had to test them to see if the result which I'm receiving from JSON is correct. So the thing that I did was to log all logs on a file on my sd card and I did something like this :

```
public void log2File(String filename, String log, int type){

   switch(type){

     case 1: // debug

     case 2: //verbose

     case 3: //warning 

      //..and etc
   }
}
```

I didn't find anything better for my solution, so that's the way which I did it.And of course you have to add your logs on a file and save it.

Hope this solutions seems good for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the eclipse logcat window to be fairly buggy with high logging volume - it won't even stay disabled if you try to turn it off.

To actually capture the desired data, I tend to use the adb logcat command from the commandline.  On linux, or presumably cygwin or osx you should be able to do:

```
adb logcat | tee logfile
```

And both see the messages flying by and have them recorded to a file.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I had the exact same problem as you. I looked everywhere for a good solution but did not find one that worked for me so I took to creating my own tool. If you are on a Mac you could use LogRabbit to do what you want to do. It could help solve your problem in two different ways.

1. You could use `adb logcat -v threadtime` on the command line and write the logs to disk and import that into LogRabbit.
2. The filtering mechanism should be plenty fast enough to handle the log volume you are talking about.

Have a look at http://lograbbit.com I hope this helps.